# Dynamics AX 2009 Developer Install

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I am trying to set my new laptop up with a developer installation of MS Dynamics AX 2009.

I start by installing MS SQL Server  2008 R2, this goes in fine, I create a new database in here.

I then launch the AX 2009 setup, I firstly install the Application Files, go through this, all is OK.
I then re-launch the AX 2009 setup, installing the AOS, I login using a specific username / password setup for the AOS.
I then re-launch the AX 2009 setup and install the Client and Debugger.

When I go to launch the AOS in Services the service gets 'stuck on "Starting" and after 5/10/15 minutes waiting and refreshing nothing happens?

Do I need to install the Database files in the AX 2009 setup as well?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to have an AX 2009 database.  Either install it via the AX 2009 installer or deploy the contoso example database from Microsoft.  Easier to install from the installer.

The first start of the AOS can take some time, but if you don't have a database, I can't imagine how it would work.

Go to (Administrative Tools>Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 Server Configuration) and click the database tab of your instance, and what does it have?  Does that database exist or is anything selected?

You should check the windows event viewer under "applications" to see issues during service startup.

/This isn't really code btw...

Comment: Hi, when I check under Database Connection in Server Config, it is connecting to the SQL Server database which I have created. I will try creating the Ax 2009 database which is part of the setup installer. I know it's not really code, but thought that I might get an answer to this problem as others have probably carried out in the installation in the past. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't just connect to any DB.  You need to install/deploy from the installer or restore a backup.  It creates a ton of tables and a few very important stored procedures that are run during the service startup.  Without those stored procedures, it's going to bomb out every time.  And no problem on the code comment, I do the same thing you do, but somebody always lets me know it's not code lol.

Comment: Hi Alex, I've re-installed everything, setting up the DB through the AX installation as well. Still in Services it just sits at "starting" I've tried waiting, refreshing, manually starting the service but nothing happens.

Comment: It's probably a permissions issue.  What does the event viewer say?  That's usually where it will tell you the exact problem.  I'd guess it's going to say something about "CreateServerSessions" or "CreateUserSessions".

Comment: The problem was that as it was the first time the services were being launched, it took a really long time, like half an hour. Now it launches ok, I went through initialization and upgrading of the client as well. Thank you Alex for your help.

Comment: No problem!  Glad you got it figured out.  The longest AOS start I had was 5.5 hours during an AX 4->2009 upgrade and it was repeatable every DB restore I did.